# Open .txt file selected on ComboBox into a RichTextBox selection

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, richtextbox

I have created multiple .txt files in `C:\Modules` and I wish to use the ComboBox as a way of selecting each one. On doing so I want the contents of that .txt file to display in a RichTextBox.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Modules");
foreach (string file in files)
ModuleSelectorComboBox.Items.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a [`SelectedIndexChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event on the `ComboBox` to set the text on the `RichTextBox`. On Visual Studio, select the combo box and on the properties window select the event. Then, double click on the SElectedIndexChanged event and add something like this, for sample:

```
private void ModuleComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
    System.EventArgs e)
{
    // get the value (file path)
    string fileName = (string) ModuleComboBox.SelectedItem;
    string filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Modules\", fileName + ".txt");         

    if (File.Exists(filePath))
        richTextBox1.AppendText(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
    else
        RichBoxBox1.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Can't get this to work and I have edited it to fit my code, any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and post what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try to define the file path on the event add the extension and path folder.